# Why am I no longer able to reconnect to remote server

Tags: iptables, firewall, kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, microk8s

I worked fine on a remote server (ubuntu-16.04), and when I ran the command from https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/issues/408 to fix a bridging problem in `microk8s (kubernetes)` I fell into a bigger problem and which isn't my domain either. I lost the connection to the server and I am no longer able to reconnect.

I suspect the following command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-masquerade --permanent
```

I don't know what the command did, I would just like to go back to the state before the execution of this damn command.

Comment: To remove *masquerade*, use the `--remove-masquerade` option. However, I am not sure if this command is the culprit. `--permanent` means that the change is only applied when you reboot (or restart the `firewalld` service). If you issue the command without `--permament`, it has an immediate effect (but the effect will disappear when rebooting). For more info, see the [manual](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html).

Comment: You _should not_ use `--permanent` until you are certain your changes work the way you intended. Your current problem is one reason why.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, it worked by executing the following command `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --remove-masquerade`

Comment: @Adil Blanco, if your issue has been solved, you can consider posting this information in a form of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I executed the command `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-masquerade --permanent` by accident, thanks to @berndbausch and @Michael Hampton comments I solved the problem by executing the following commands:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --remove-masquerade --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```